# AWS api Gateway Client sdk uses promise and angular 2 uses observable

Tags: angular, aws-sdk

I have a AWS api Gateway Client sdk which uses promise and angular 2 uses observable's will it be compatible with each other ...

I mean can I convert the promise object returned from AWS sdk into a angular 2 observable ?? or will I have to import angular 2 promise and match the returned object type ??

Answer (score 1):

by the grace of the Almighty :)

Observable.fromPromise() is a method in Rxjs - using which you can convert a promise into an observable and Observable.toPromise() convert a existing observable into promise.